# How to use $q.deffer to chain ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, request, promise

I need to do this: browser have to make N requests to the server, requests mustn't be async, next requests are starting after previous requests will stop.

I can write some `function A` with `for i < N i++` and calling this `function A` again recursively to do this, but it is not beautifull at all. Also, this called callback hell. I want some more beautifull solution.

I found `deffered` objects. Some says, it can help me to escape callback hell. I want something like this. `setTimeout` there is imitate one async request:

```
    function foo1(some) {
        debugger;
        setTimeout(function foo1async() {
            debugger;
            deffered.resolve();
        }, 500);
        return deffered.promise;
    }

    function foo2(some) {
        debugger;
        setTimeout(function foo2async() {
            debugger;
            deffered.reject();
        }, 500);
        return deffered.promise;
    }

    function foo3() {
        debugger;
        setTimeout(function foo3async() {
            debugger;
            deffered.resolve();
        }, 500);
        return deffered.promise;
    }

    var deffered;
    function doChain() {
        debugger;
        deffered = $q.defer();
        var promise = deffered.promise;
        promise.then(foo1);
        promise.then(foo2);
        promise.then(foo3);
        promise["finally"](function () {
            debugger;
        });
        deffered.resolve();
    }
```

1. I expect foo1 to be called, then foo1async will be called and resolve deffered object.
2. `foo2` must be called, then `foo2async` is called. 
   3.Now I expect, that `foo3` wouldn't start, because deffered is rejected in `foo2async`. After that I expect foo in `finally` section called.

Actually, I have this:
`foo1`, `foo2` and `foo3` are called. Then foo in `finally` section called. Then `foo1async`, `foo2async` and `foo3async` funtions are called.

How I can get what I am expecting?

Actually, I will have something like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    (function (iter) {
        promise.then(function () {
            foo(iter);
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You got a few things wrong here.

First, you use a deferred to convert a callback-based async function into a promise-based - but each one needs its own `deferred.promise` and thus its own `deferred`. Actually, I prefer to use the `$q` constructor instead:

```
function fooN(input){
  return $q(function(resolve, reject){
    setTimeout(function(){
      resolve(input + "; some more data");
    }, 500);
  });
}
```

(you could use `var deferred = $q.defer()` as well)

`fooN` now returns a promise, so you don't need to use `$q.defer()` anymore.

In fact, if the async function already was promise-based, like `$timeout` or `$http`, then you wouldn't have needed a `deferred` at all, for ex:

```
function fooN(input){
  return $timeout(function(){
    return input + "; some more data";
  }, 500);
})
```

So, let's assume that `foo1`, `foo2` and `foo3` are implemented like `fooN` - all returning promises.

To make the calls sequential, you would need to chain promises - not to attach multiple handlers to the some root promise.

I'll break it down for you:

```
function doChain(){
  var foo1Promise = foo1();
  var foo2AfterFoo1Promise = foo1Promise.then(foo2);
  var foo3AfterFoo2Promise = foo2AfterFoo1Promise.then(foo3);

  var promise = foo3AfterFoo2Promise.then(function(finalData){
    return doSomeProcessing(finalData); // if needed
  });

  promise.catch(function(error){
    // "rethrow", if can't handle
    return $q.reject({msg: "Some error occurred"});
  })

  return promise;
}
```

Or, the same, more concise:

```
function doChain(p){
  return foo1(p)
          .then(foo2)
          .then(foo3)
          .then(function(finalData){
            return doSomeProcessing(finalData);
          })
          .catch(function(error){
            return $q.reject({msg: "Some error occurred"});
          });
}
```

A "promised" return value of each function is an input to the next chained function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $q.all method. For instance:

```
var promises = [promise1, promise2, ...];

$q.all(promises).then(function () {
// do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens now is that all foo* promises depend on the single `promise`; when it gets resolved all are triggered. In ASCII art the dependencies are:

```
        ┎ foo1
promise ╁ foo2
        ┖ foo3
```

What you want is:

```
function doChain() {
    foo1()
        .then(foo2)
        .then(foo3)
    ;
}
```

No need for the extra `promise`. No callback hell either!

Comment: And what exactly returns foo1, foo2, foo3? Also, I must have possiibility to cancel chain, from foo2 function, for example. Can you provide more broad example?

Comment: What do you mean "what returns foo1,..."? They are functions in your own code from the question! The question does *not* mention cancelling the chain, please do not insert more questions in comments - especially with vague specifications. E.g. what triggers the cancellation?